# Android Studio auto-creates JNI functions in weird file

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio has a very useful "Create JNI function for XYZ" feature.

However, it always puts the generated function in the same (wrong) CPP file.

Is there any way we can specify which CPP/C file we want the auto-generated C function to be created in?

[image]

Comment: Hi, I worked on this feature and we have plans to improve the behavior. For now unfortunately there is no way to pick allow user picking a file. However, you should be able to open the desired c++ file and just type `jni` or the name of the function, then Android Studio should complete the same snippet for missing JNI implementations.